# How to clear bad sectors in hard disk using ubuntu

Tags: 12.04

My hard disk has developed more than 1200 bad sectors and it is failing to install any operating system. I am using ubuntu 12.04 through my pen drive. I need to zero fill my hard disk. Please advice.

Comment: Buy a new hard disk.

Answer (score 9):

Well you have a lot of bad sectors.  My advise is to replace the drive.  But if you still want to mark those bad sectors, then you can use fsck.  fsck is used to check and optionally repair one or more Linux file systems.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo fsck /dev/sd*  (replace * with your device ID)
```

**Note:  When dealing with any hard drive issue please make sure that you have a current backup of all you information.**

**The "fsck" command stands for "file system check"; it scans the disk for bad sectors and labels the ones that aren't working.**

If you want to zero out the drive, just follow Piskvor's answer.

Comment: That's not what `fsck` does; it checks and restores improperly unmounted *filesystems* (i.e. data structures). Bad sectors are *hardware* errors on the underlying *disk*.

Comment: @Piskvor The "fsck" command stands for "file system check"; it scans the disk for bad sectors and labels the ones that aren't working.

Comment: Interesting. I apologize, you are right after all: this *is* one of `fsck`'s functions - although `fsck` can't repair or reallocate the bad sectors, it can mark them as bad *in the FS*, so that the FS will not even try to use these sectors. Even though this doesn't *solve* the underlying problem, it can *sidestep* it (for a small number of bad sectors).

Comment: @Piskvor  Don't apologize, we're all here learning from each others.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your specific question: `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX` will overwrite disk `/dev/sdX` with zeroes. Use with caution; **there is no "undo" for this**.

To address the underlying problem: if your hard disk has this many errors, it *will* fail catastrophically in the very near future, and you will lose anything that's written on it; replace it with a working one ASAP. Overwriting it with zeroes will *not* eliminate the bad sectors, and only postpones the problem.